# Unable to re-derive Inverse Transfer Matrix

Tags: acoustics, linear-algebra

I don't get the same result as the book when computing the inverse of this matrix.

For context, I'm rederiving some equations from a book on acoustic waves in periodic structures, specifically a chapter on the transfer matrix method, which relates acoustic pressure and particle velocity in a $1D$ waveguide at $x=0$ and at $x=L$ where $L$ is the length of the waveguide. The author prefers to express $x=0$ as a transformation applied to $x=L$ and not the other way around. Because the equation is initially expressed as a transformation applied to $x=0$, the matrix that gives the transfer function has to be inverted, giving the following definition for the transfer matrix, $\textbf{T}$
\begin{equation}
        \textbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(kL) & -iZ\sin(kL)\\\cos(kL) &-i\frac{1}{Z}\sin(kL)\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(kL)&iZ\sin(kL)\\i\frac{1}{Z}\sin(kL)&\cos(kL)\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I don't get this result when doing the calculation by hand or with a symbolic solver. Instead, by the definition of inverse matrix $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\textbf{adj}A$$ I get:

\begin{equation}
       \textbf{ T}=\frac{1}{i\sin(kL)\cos(kL)(Z-\frac{1}{Z})}\begin{bmatrix} -i\frac{1}{Z}\sin(kL) & iZ\sin(kL)\\ -\cos(kL) & \cos(kL)\end{bmatrix} =
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{\cos(kL)(Z^2-1)} & \frac{Z^2}{\cos(kL)(z^2-1)} \\ i\frac{Z}{-\sin(kL)+Z^2\sin(kL)} & -i\frac{Z}{-\sin(kL)+Z^2\sin(kL)}\end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation}
Which as far as I can tell does not simplify/rearrange to the matrix given in the equation for $\textbf{T}$. Am I missing something here?

If this is a question better suited to maths SE please forgive me, I'm very new to this forum. I am happy to take down and repost there.

**Solution:** there was a typo in the book. The correct expression checks out and should in fact be:

\begin{equation}
        \textbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(kL) & -iZ\sin(kL)\\-i\frac{1}{Z}\sin(kL)&\cos(kL)\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(kL)&iZ\sin(kL)\\i\frac{1}{Z}\sin(kL)&\cos(kL)\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Could you specify what $Z$ is? I don't see any immediate mistakes, maybe there are some additional algebraic manipulations one can make.

Comment: Also, Mathematica returns me different answer when I try to invert $T$, namely $T^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos k L & -i Z \sin k L \\ - \frac{i}{Z} \sin k L & \cos k L \end{pmatrix}$, which is different to the matrix you're trying to invert. Are you sure you copied the expression correctly?

Comment: It's certainly true that those matrices aren't inverses of each other, so there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: @mb28025 your answer is very close to what appears in the book, just off by a couple negative signs. $Z = \rho c$ is characteristic acoustic impedance, where $\rho$ is the density of the medium and $c$ is wave speed defined as $c = \omega/k$ where $\omega$ is angular frequency and $k$ wavenumber.